# Plotting two different arrays of different lengths

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have two arrays. One is the raw signal of length (1000, )  and the other one is the smooth signal of length (100,). I want to visually represent how the smooth signal represents the raw signal. Since these arrays are of different length, I am not able to plot them one over the other. Is there a way to do so in matplotlib?

Thanks!

Comment: you cannot plot two different length arrays. maybe you can plot them separately using two different `x-axes`

Comment: Define the _x_ values for both.

Comment: You need to define a different `x` vector for both. For instance, `x1=np.linspace(0, 1, len(signal1))`,  `x2= np.linspace(0, 1, len(signal2))` and then plot them as `plt.plot(x1, signal1)`,  `plt.plot(x2, signal2)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As [rth suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003155/plotting-two-different-arrays-of-different-lengths/31003327#comment50034010_31003155), define

```
x1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
```

and then plot raw versus x1, and smooth versus x2:

```
plt.plot(x1, raw)
plt.plot(x2, smooth)
```

[`np.linspace(0, 1, N)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) returns an array of length `N` with equally spaced values from 0 to 1 (inclusive).

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2015)

raw = (np.random.random(1000) - 0.5).cumsum()
smooth = raw.reshape(-1,10).mean(axis=1)

x1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
plt.plot(x1, raw)
plt.plot(x2, smooth)
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if the larger array size is not divisible by the smaller array size.

Answer (score 1):

You will need two different x-axes for this job. You cannot plot two variables with different lengths in one single plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.random.random(100) # the smooth signal
x = np.linspace(0,100,100) # it's x-axis

y1 = np.random.random(1000) # the raw signal
x1 = np.linspace(0,100,1000) # it's x-axis

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.plot(x,y,label='smooth-signal')
ax.legend(loc='best')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.plot(x1,y1,label='raw-signal')
ax2.legend(loc='best')

plt.suptitle('Smooth-vs-raw signal')
fig.show()
```

[image]